# Karma AngularJS bootstrap and window variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to write a test for my application and I'm loading files in with Karma into PhantomJS. The problem is that one of the files causes a page reload due to window variables.

The files are included like so:

```
files: [
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'js/**/*.js'
]
```

The main application file (main.js) contains this:

```
if ( window.top !=== window.self ){
    window.location.href = 'someOtherURL.html';
}

// PhantomJS 2.1.1 ERROR
// Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

So none of my tests run because the inclusion of this one file stops execution due to page reload.

My question is, how can I set the window variables so that I can run this test?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no global window object in test env, you may put following hack string before tests:

```
window = window || {};
```

Comment: does this go in karma config?

Comment: For example: you may put it in separate file and include in test file first

Answer (score 0):

The reason that that window.top and window.self are not the same is that karma loads tests in an iframe by default.

added this to my karma config:

```
client: {
    useIframe: false
},
```

and now it works fine.